# How can I achieve this lighting in blender..?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

[image]
I am really curious how can I achieve this lighting in blender

Comment: Well I need to know about that bluish light

Answer (score 2):

Like you would do in the real world, by adding lights behind the columns. You can do it with long planes and an emission shader or with long area lights.

The blue the light is the effect of white light reflected on a blue surface.

[image]

Comment: ..and you've managed to create a floor without a trip hazard... :)

Comment: @RobinBetts to comply with the [code of conduct](https://blender.stackexchange.com/conduct)... so new users don't trip